# Find the length of perpendicular as shown

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image: Cyclic Quadrilateral]

$ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.Find $x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a = FE$ and $b = EC$. Clearly we have $a+b = 7$. By similar triangles we have $x/7 = b/5$ and $x/3 = (3+a)/5$. We now have a system of three equations in three variables. Solving gives $x=4.2$.

Answer (score 3):

I think I got it. It uses similarity of triangles.

[image]